# Select of a section of a web page and output all js used there?

Tags: javascript

Is there an application that allows me to select a section of a web page, and then outputs all js used there? I've been told I can do this with Chrome Inspector, but haven't had any success so far.

Example:

On this page - http://preview.oklerthemes.com/porto/2.7.0/page-left-sidebar.html - there is a tabbed box in the sidebar. I want to easily grab all the JS/CSS needed for that box. I usually use Inspector to look at all the styles, and go and grab theme from each CSS file, but I don't know how to do this for the JS.

Comment: Please clarify your question, give examples

Comment: Well js is a bit complicated. You can do it but it's not very practical to do and I would not recommend trying to do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from your question what you're asking.

Are you trying to see what JS causes writes or changes to a particular part of a web page? The easiest way would be to open the page with the element inspector, right-click a particular chunk of HTML and stick a breakpoint on modifications.

The next time a function causes any changes, the breakpoint will trigger and you'll be able to crawl up the call stack to see what the cause was.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to know which lines of js from which files are used for a particular section on a web page.

Comment: @MattyPantaloons - it doesn't really work that way. You could have lots of functions that will help do stuff around a particular piece of content, and call lots of other functions to do that work. Especially if it's an SPA under somethink like Angular; the dependency tree in terms of functions will be huge. The content could be grabbed by XHR too. You could use the above technique to reverse the basic implementation of key features, but you're probably going to be writing your own implementation rather than just copying a few lines of JS. And the reversing will not be just a few minutes' work.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Better off grabbing the clean tabbed component from bootstrap in that case, I guess. Thanks again, Jimmy.